# How to get attribute of HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a newb question, but it makes me pulling my hairs:

```
<div class="search-input-field">
  <input type="text" value="amazon" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search">
</div>
```

I would like to get the value of this input when user mouseOut. How can I do this using jQuery/javaScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.val()` to get the value of a form element:

```
var value = $('#search').val();
```

You can also use `.attr()` to get an attribute for an element:

```
var placeholderText = $('#search').attr('value');
```

Docs:

- `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val
- `.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr

An example of your desired code:

```
$('#search').on('mouseout', function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Notice that you can get the value of an input element inside an event handler with `this.value` which will perform much faster than using `$(this).val()`.

**[Suggestion]** - If you want to get the value after the user has finished editing the value of the input then I suggest using the `blur` event (`mouseout` fires when the user moves the cursor over the element, then away):

```
$('#search').on('blur', function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

Comment: blur != mouseout. I think OP wants it onmouseout. Not sure why.. but that is what is there in his post.

Comment: @Jasper About the `.val()` vs `.attr('value')` - unless I'm missing something, they return the same value (i.e. whatever user puts there), at least for `input`, live example: http://jsfiddle.net/xHwwW/. Did you mean something else by what you said?

Comment: @SKS That's a good point. I'll make sure it's know that using the `blur` event is just a suggestion.

Comment: @icyrock.com Thanks for the input. You're right, I'm not sure why I thought that, probably thinking of some other function (`.prop()` vs. `.attr()` maybe...). Answer Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You going to need to implement the `mouseout` event handler first and then you can use `this.value` the value of the input and `.attr` to get the value of any non-standard attribute.

```
var $search = $('#search');
$search.mouseout(function () {
   alert(this.value);
   alert(this.name);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CvhuC/)

Further Reading,

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[.mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

Comment: Undeclared `$search` (OK, I know it's in your demo), but then you're going to repeat `$("#search")` within the function? Why not use `$search` again, or, better, just use `this.value` and `this.name`?

Answer (score 2):

Plain JS way:

```
var myValue = document.getElementsByName("search")[0].value;
```

or

```
var myValue = document.getElementById("search").value;
```

Cross browser binding is sometimes problematic, but it's basicly something like:

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('onmouseout',function () {
    var myValue = this.value;
},false);
```

jQuery way:

```
var myValue = $('#search').val();
```

or

```
var myValue = $('input[name="search"]').val();
```

binding

```
$('#search').on('click', function() {var myValue = this.value});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('div.search-input-field').mouseout(function () {

            alert($('div.search-input-field input:first').val());

        });

    });
```